# Reflecting on class with property of type defined in deparate assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, reflection

I have following WCF class:

```
namespace BusinessServices.Exposure.Data
{
    [DataContract]
    public class RiskItemBO : ExposureBO
    {
        [DataMember]
        public RiskItemBusinessService RiskItemBusinessService { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The `RiskItemBusinessService` is a class which is defined in some other DLL and consists of `String`, `Int` and `Short` variables. I have methods to generate random values for these data types.

I have following questions:

I am using Type.GetProperties() to get all the properties within a class, which does give me the name of the property `RiskItemBusinessService`, however, when I try to do `PropertyInfo.PropertyType`, I get `FileNotFoundException` (`RiskItemBusinessService`, is in a different DLL). For this, I am catching the exception and loading the DLL into the catch clause, but still, when I try to do `PropertyInfo.SetValue` I again get the `FileNotFoundException` even though I have just loaded the DLL using `Assembly.LoadFile`.

Comment: Try using this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies.aspx

Comment: @Xtudio: Is there a way to load multiple assemblies, so I don't get the `FileNotFoundException` ?

Comment: You have to _reference_ the assemblies you use. You can't dynamically load them and have them suddenly start working.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I understand that I need to reference the assemblies when I am writing a class. However, I am trying to create an object of this class from a different method using reflection. I will have access to only DLLs and not source code while creating the object.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you need the source. You need the assemblies, and it must be possible for .NET to find them when you need them. Try the same thing without reflection and see if it works. It will not.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I have the assemblies. They are in the same folder as my initial DLL. If you want I can post the source code which I am using for reflection as well.

Comment: I mean, try to access the type directly, without reflection, and see if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a case were you will want to utilize reused assemblies in your service reference on the client.

Essentially, as John was pointing out, you add a reference to the assembly containing `RiskItemBusinessService`. Then you go to the Service Reference configuration and enable the option to reuse referenced types, and for specific references, ticking the assembly you just added. This re-generates the service reference without the proxies for types specified. From here your services will be constructung variables from the assembly references so you should be able to use it as you would any other type.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. Still not exactly what I was looking for, but good for now. I was hoping to make a generic tool which is environment and reference independent. To which, if you feed the DLL path and class name, it will create a instance of that class and will recursively populate the rest of the values inside that class.